# Monterey: remove the word "urgent" from Calendar notifications?

Tags: notifications, calendar, ical, monterey

After upgrading to Monterey I get notifications of events that are about to start with an "URGENT" banner in the alert box.

Is there *any* way to not have that word?

It may seem like nothing, but it kicks up my stress levels every time. It feels as if my calm & understated British butler has been replaced by an aggressive, panicky guy from marketing. I want him out.

Comment: This sounds like a translation quirk. On my computer in America, the alerts say "Time Sensitive" because it's a notification for a calendar event, i.e. time sensitive.

Comment: @Ezekiel oh interesting. Indeed I have it set to French — I assumed it was also urgent in English, as that would be the natural reverse translation.

Comment: It says Time Sensitive in UK English too - though even that is irritating; they're **all** time sensitive, because that's when I told it to remind me. It doesn't also have to mention why I told it to.

Comment: Damien - I'd be inclined to change the question to 'time sensitive' because, as it's an English language site, a majority probably see it that way.

Comment: @DamienD If you go to System Preferences > Notifications > Calendar and uncheck "Allow time sensitive alerts" (or appropriate translation of course) does this change anything?